# Input/output error and fsck

Tags: linux, filesystems, data-recovery

recently I couldn't mount my hard drive so I booted with a live cd and doing a fsck on that partition. it said Deleted inode 992193 has zero dtime.  Fix
i entered y and another one it showed me this prompt again and I entered ctrl-C

now I'm able to mount that hard disk. but my problem:
I can't access some files it says Input/output error
If I do fsck again and answer all prompts like (Deleted inode 992193 has zero dtime.  Fix) to yes my data will be recovered?! my another data will be lost?!
I'm not technical in hard disks so I can't read the manuals. it has some technical issues

Answer (score 6):

This is off-topic here, but you need to let the fsck finish, or your filesystem will remain corrupt and you will continue to have problems with it.

Run `fsck -y`, let it complete, and then you should be ok (most of the time).

Answer (score 1):

Watch out with performing `fsck` on a failing drive. If it's an hardware issue, better **first** make an image of what is still readable with something like [ddrescue](https://savannah.gnu.org/projects/ddrescue/) (see that you get the GNU one, it's the better of the 2 ddrescues that are around).

trying to fix the filesystem on a failing disk might wear it out, and limit the amount of data that you'll be able to recover. So first copy, and try fixing the FS on the copy.

Comment: I made a backup by dd and do fsck -y after my backup, so my corrupted data has been removed! I didn't want to remove them! so I thing I have to recover my backup data and recover corrupt data by testdisk!

Comment: Test disk also can work with an image you've made. No need to restore it to hard drive.